# SQL Query to return count of rows until certain criteria is met

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got the following dataset ordered by a specific column:

```
ratio
-----
1
1
1
0.8333
1
1.6667
3.3333
1
```

And I want to count the rows where ratio equals 1, but **only** until I reach a row where ratio **is not** 1.
For the above dataset my expected result would be *3* (the first three rows).

Of course I could do this in the code, but I just wondered whether there's an SQL solution to this.

Comment: Post the code that produces that result

Comment: What is the column name for order by ?

Comment: It does not really matter, but in my case it was "updated_at"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that the data is "ordered by a specific column".  If so, you can simply do:

```
select count(*)
from table t
where specificcolumn < (select min(t2.specificcolumn)
                        from table t2
                        where t2.ratio <> 1)
```

Depending on the ordering, the `<` may need to be `>`.

Note:  this assumes that the specific column has unique values.  If the values are not unique, then you need multiple columns for a unique key.

Comment: Thanks, that works like a charm! I've used the following query now:
select count(*) from table where updated_at > (select max(updated_at) from table where ratio <> 1)

Answer (score 1):

If you have another primary key column in the table:

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`)
FROM `table`
WHERE `ratio` = 1
AND `id` < (SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE `ratio` != 1 ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use update

```
declare @cnt int, @flag int
select @cnt = 0, @flag = null
update #t set
    @cnt = @cnt + case when @flag is null then ratio else 0 end,  
    @flag = case when @flag is null and ratio != 1 then 1 else @flag end
select @cnt
```

I am using t-sql syntax, but you may find something similar in

Answer (score 0):

Gordon's solution does not work when table consists only of 1s.
Maybe this solution will work for you

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS CNT
  FROM
(
  SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN ratio = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(ORDER BY SortColumn DESC) AS NotOneCount
    FROM YourTable
) t
WHERE t.NotOneCount = 0;
```